# Getting fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory #include <jni.h>

Tags: java, c++, c, dll, java-native-interface

I want to get two functions from a dynamic shared object library [developped with C/C++]. To call this DLL from my java application, I have used Java JNI. However, after compiling the Java application I find the compiler has generated a headerfile jni.h. I added the file in my DLL, but when I tried compiling the DLL project, I got the following compilation error:

> fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory  #include

I tried to include the header file directories :

```
/I "$(JAVA_HOME)\include" /I "$(JAVA_HOME)\include\win32"
```

Without any success

the header file **JNIServerLib.h**

```
    /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class jniserver_JNIServer */

#ifndef _Included_jniserver_JNIServer
#define _Included_jniserver_JNIServer
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     jniserver_JNIServer
 * Method:    BZ_receiving
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jniserver_JNIServer_BZ_receiving
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     jniserver_JNIServer
 * Method:    BZ_sending
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jniserver_JNIServer_BZ_sending
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Simple java program  **JNIServer.java**

```
public class JNIServer {
    public native void BZ_receiving();
    public native void BZ_sending();
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("JNIServer");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JNIServer().BZ_receiving();
        new JNIServer().BZ_sending();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably have a look at JNA, and see whether it can simplify your life

Comment: Is the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable declared, and does it point to the correct directory for the JDK?

Comment: it's just a symbol of : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\include and
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\include\win32

Comment: @fge  [articl](https://www.facebook.com/notes/th%C3%A9-passerby/dll-jni-sous-netbeans/203707350017862) this is an artical of method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a gap between `/I` and the filepath. Changing it to

```
/I"$(JAVA_HOME)\include" /I"$(JAVA_HOME)\include\win32"
```

should work.

Comment: **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\include**    and 
**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\include\win32**   but it doesn't work !!!

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

The following command looks for the include files requested by MAIN.c in the following order: first in the directory containing MAIN.c, then in the \INCLUDE directory, then in the \MY\INCLUDE directory, and finally in the directories assigned to the INCLUDE environment variable.

```
CL /I \INCLUDE /I\MY\INCLUDE MAIN.C
```

Make sure the header file is in one of the Include directories.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx)

Comment: [link](https://www.facebook.com/notes/th%C3%A9-passerby/dll-jni-sous-netbeans/203707350017862) this is an artical of method